# How can I tell if a string has any non-ASCII characters in it?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, ascii

I'm looking to detect internationalized domain names and local portions in email addresses, and would like to know if there is a quick and easy way to do this with regex or otherwise in Javascript.

Comment: What do you mean by ASCII? Remember that NUL (\0), BEL (\7 - causes PC to beep), ESC (\033) are also valid ASCII characters but most would't consider them to be valid ASCII text.

Comment: @slebetman very fair point to add.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try with this regex. It tests for all ascii characters that *have some meaning* in a string, from space `32` to tilde `126`:

```
var ascii = /^[ -~]+$/;

if ( !ascii.test( str ) ) {
  // string has non-ascii characters
}
```

**Edit:** with tabs and newlines:

```
/^[ -~\t\n\r]+$/;
```

Comment: So tabs and newlines don't count as OK characters?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Right... I added that case as well.

Comment: @elclanrs I'm glad that you differentiated, though, because for many usecases they wouldn't be desired.

Comment: All Ascii characters have meanings, but not all of them are allowed or suitable in a particular context. The variable name `ascii` would be misleading here.

Answer (score 33):

This should do it...

```
var hasMoreThanAscii = /^[\u0000-\u007f]*$/.test(str);
```

...also...

```
var hasMoreThanAscii = str
                       .split("")
                       .some(function(char) { return char.charCodeAt(0) > 127 });
```

ES6 goodness...

```
let hasMoreThanAscii = [...str].some(char => char.charCodeAt(0) > 127);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `+` be a `*`? This requires that the string has characters in it, but the empty string `""` fulfills the OP's strict requirements: it doesn't have any non-ASCII characters in it.

Comment: If you change your `.filter` to `.some`, you can get rid of `.length > 0`

Comment: @user1689607 True. I'll also get rid of a bit of browser support ;)

Comment: Nah, any browser that supports `.filter()`, supports `.some()`. They're both ES5 additions. :)

Comment: @alex: Sorry, my regex doesn't work somehow (also I deleted the post before seeing your reply, sorry)

Comment: the second one was broken for me before I added a `return` before the `char.charCodeAt...`

Comment: `/^[\u0-\u7f]*$/.test("a/b")` returns false for some reason, it turns out the fix is `/^[\u0000-\u007f]*$/`. I've edited the answer.

Comment: The variable name is inverted.

/^[\u0000-\u007f]*$/.test(str) = true when ascii
so variable name should be: var isAscii = /^[\u0000-\u007f]*$/.test(str)

Comment: Or it should be negated like `var hasMoreThanAscii = !/^[\u0000-\u007f]*$/.test(str);`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Answer (score 11):

`charCodeAt` can be used to get the character code at a certain position in a string.

```
function isAsciiOnly(str) {
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
        if (str.charCodeAt(i) > 127)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the largest ASCII character 127?

Comment: I believe the largest ASCII code now is 255 check here http://www.ascii-code.com/

Answer (score 1):

Simpler alternative to [@alex's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13522792/856465):

```
const hasNonAsciiCharacters = str => /[^\u0000-\u007f]/.test(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.match() or regex.test() to achieve this. Following function will return true if the string contains only ascii characters.

**string.match()**

```
function isAsciiString(text) {
    let isAscii = true;
    if (text && !text.match(/^[\x00-\x7F]+$/g)) {
        isAscii = false;
    }
    return isAscii;
}
```

**regex.test()**

```
function isAsciiString(text) {
    return /^[\x00-\x7F]+$/g.test(text);
}
```

**Example**

```
console.log(isAsciiString("hello"));   // true
console.log(isAsciiString("hello©"));  // false
```